# iOS: Are there any open-source Launcher Views like the home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am looking for an open source project that allows me to have a launcher view like the iPhone/iPad home screen with the icons.  Now know that Three20 has this but I do NOT want to use it.

Are there any alternatives out there?

Comment: Only one i've seen is three20, may i ask why you don't want to use it?

Comment: Because it is a massive library to add for just one small feature.

Comment: I think they have recently broken it into modules so you can just get pieces you need (though i'm not positive about that launch pad part..i just use the photo album/viewer)

Comment: Ah you are right, well that is good news! Post it as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Three20 ([Link](http://three20.info)) has recently broken their library into modules for specific uses so you don't have to use the whole massive package.  It seems like the best option easily available. (reposted from comment)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better one to suit your needs

https://github.com/jarada/myLauncher

Answer (score 1):

This one is better and recently updated among all available option.

https://github.com/heikomaass/HMLauncherView