# UICollectionView like iOS Home Screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I wanna make an UICollectionView like iOS Home Screen. I found several (and good) samples like:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uicollectionview-layouts/

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/sespringboard

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/aqgridview

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/namenu

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mgbox2

[iOS: Are there any open-source Launcher Views like the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531246/ios-are-there-any-open-source-launcher-views-like-the-home-screen)

All libraries above work well. Editing, removing and animating is not a problem. But combining two cells into a new group, well, none of the libraries was able to do it. I heavily searched and I didn't find anything.
Does anybody know any libraries to combine two cells with drag and drop?!?!
Or at least has some tips on how to make?!?

Comment: have you looked at [AQGridview](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sections to group items and SupplementaryElements to decorate groups.

Or

You can also just create 2 kinds of different UICollectionViewCells: one normal cell + one group cell.

If your data source reflects grouping it should straight-forward to decide which one to return in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: .