# How to Rearrange and delete UIViews in UIScrollview like apps rearranging in iOS Home screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have some UIViews in UIScrollview and added a page controller to scrollview.
Is it possible to delete the views and rearrange views using drag&drop like apps rearranging in iOS Home screen?

Please provide me some guidelines or references.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519302/uicollectionview-like-ios-home-screen

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to run the loop after the deleted view.

Suppose that there are 20 view and you are deleting 11th View then you have to run loop from 12th to 20th view and rearrange them to one previous view's frame.

In this case you have to store all subviews in a NSMutableArray.

**Another Best Way**

You can use `UICollectionView` when you will delete or remove the any item from `UICollectionView` it will automatically rearrange the position of all views.

for a tutorial of `UICollectionView`  have a look into following link

you just have to call following Code to delete item of `UICollectionView`

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
```

[A Springboard-Like Layout With the UICollectionView Class](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-springboard-like-layout-with-the-uicollectionview-class--mobile-13426)

Answer (score 1):

To implement what homescreen of iPhone does, you should use only one object to catch touches of user.

And what you want to implement, it's called **GridView**

You can research on http://cocoacontrols.com with keyword: **grid**

This is best example to learn how to do that : https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView